# Bootloop using Sony Xperia Arc S (LT18i)

Tags: boot-loop, sony-xperia-arc

Hey guys so I'm in boot loop. Yes I know there are many guides all over saying how to fix it but I have tried many of them and they didnt work.

What happens is I start the phone, it shows the boot image and then restarts after a time.

I can boot into the Recovery mode by spamming the back button when the Logo comes. And can install zip files from the SD card.
I also have tried flashtool to restore it to stock but when i try flashing it detects my device "Device connected in flash mode" but when i try toflash it, it gives an error "Error flashing. Aborted".

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the caches (e.g. from within the recovery menu)? A last ressort would be a factory-reset, if wiping cache & dalvik does not help.

Comment: done all of those as well

Comment: Including a factory reset? Then maybe you've flashed an incompatible ROM?

Answer (score 1):

I have just repaired the boot loop of my Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc (LT15i, boot loop caused by activating Bluetooth !!) just by unlocking the bootloader of my phone - by following these steps:

1. I retrieved the IMEI-Number of my phone. It's on the sticker under the battery - it's the 15-cypher-number beside the serial number.
2. I went to http://developer.sonymobile.com/unlockbootloader/ - selected my phone type, input an email address, and received a unique link from Sony by doing so.
3. Following this link I could type in my IMEI number (without the last cypher !! - that means only 14 cyphers - and without the hyphen).
4. The website emitted a code and a software line like this one:

   ```
   fastboot -i 0x0fce oem unlock 0xTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
   ```

   (All the T's stand for the code, the rest has to be typed in like this.)
5. I copied the above line in the program fastboot (check elsewhere to learn how to work with this program and your phone). I typed in the above line given from the Sony website. After a few seconds the bootloader was unlocked.
6. I restarted the phone, and then Android 4.0 was working again !!

Answer (score 0):

Download flashtool and the phone firmware. Start application and press lihtning button. Choose your downloaded firmware and press flash button. Follow instructions and wait untill flash finish.

Comment: Provide the corresponding links.. The answer is too generic that it applies to all Android devices on Earth.

Answer (score -1):

Try reflashing your custom ROM and clear Dalvik and Cache and do a factory reset after that . And make sure you are flashing a ROM compatible to your device.

Answer (score -1):

Repair via [SUS](http://www.sonymobile.com/in/tools/update-service/).

1. Install SUS
2. Connect your phone
3. Select your phone from SUS
4. Follow the instruction
5. website no longer avalibale