# My phone not registering to 2G (GSM only) network

Tags: mobile-network, gsm, sony-xperia-neo-l

I am using a Sony Xperia Neo L (MT25i). After updating the OS, my phone not registering to 2G (GSM only mode) network. It works perfectly with 3G (WCDMA only or WCDMA proffered mode) network. While searching for network I can see all the 2G network. I try changed my SIM, but for all the SIM its the same. While googling many are reported this issue, but couldn't find a solution. I don't know whether I am posting this on right place. Since it happened after the OS update I am posting it here. My current Android version is 4.0.4

**Update**
I am from INDIA and my baseband version is 8x55A-AAABQMAZM-203028G-87. Does any one have other baseband on Neo L (MT25i)?

Comment: Did you try resetting to factory defaults?

Comment: yes i tried resetting. Even i tried re-flashing using `sony bridge`

Comment: I think this is probably caused by updated baseband. Can you flash older baseband only?

Comment: if you don't mind can you provide me some link please...

Comment: give me few minutes

Comment: Wait... why 2G network... care to elaborate *what* reason is there to use 2G, when 3G is the norm?

Comment: Have you confirmed your APN settings are correct?

Comment: @Mr.Buster My issue is with GSM network, not with Internet connectivity.

Comment: @ShineethHamza did you flash via flashtool?

Comment: If yes did you notice the line `this file is ignored simlock.ta` while flashing

Comment: @sameer I checked the SIM lock on service menu after flashing. There is no SIM lock. all are open.

Comment: @ShineethHamza you flashed ftf or updated via pcc

Comment: @sameer I tried both.

Comment: I suggest a repair via SUS

Comment: While flashing via flashtool is the line `this file is ignored simlock.ta` appears as red. Also is your pc language set to english when flashing

Comment: @sameer No i haven't got the message `this file is ignored simlock.ta` on flash tool. System language was set to English only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14132/discussion-between-sameer-and-shineeth-hamza)

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you have tried resetting to factory defaults and re-flashing same update, I believe the causes might be caused by updated baseband. I would try reflashing different original firmware. You can also flash `baseband` only via `flashtool` so maybe it might be worth trying to flash baseband from the firmware that worked. YMMV.

You can find links to download FTF (original firmware) for your device:

- Build 4.1.B.0.587 - http://d-h.st/Vft
- Build 4.1.B.0.626 - http://goo.gl/hAfwI
- Build 4.1.B.0.631 - http://d-h.st/iVF

Sources & more info:

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2047914
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1952333
- http://www.flashtool.net/index.php

Comment: My bad luck dude.... Its not working. Getting same error  while trying to register on 2G network.

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: @Mr.Buster selected netw. (****) unavailable

Answer (score 0):

Try flashing the latest ftf file from [here](http://d-h.st/iVF). If you are already in .631 build try flashing the [baseband](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByNPPw6PDxkkVGlKcWFrQ2RPSXM/edit?pli=1) alone. (Try downloading the ftf file again and flash).

Comment: @ShineethHamza Try changing `Settings->Mobile network->Preferred Network->GSM only`

Comment: @ShineethHamza working??

Comment: Not working dude.... still the same.. ;(

Comment: Do you know any version of baseband other than 87 for MT25i?

Comment: @ShineethHamza No I will suggest you to repair via pc companion or SUS

Comment: See the answer for how to repair http://android.stackexchange.com/a/67841/53576 

http://android.stackexchange.com/a/66409/53576

Comment: still the issue remain.... looks like I have to take it to service center :(

Answer (score -3):

Simple solution, just reflash radio for your device and it should work. If not contact your provider.